Printing subprocess snort alerts
I'm using subprocess popen to execute a command to start snort's sniffing. When I execute this manually, alerts are printed to stdout and show up on the terminal. However, when using popen, no alerts are showing up.
sniff_command = "sudo snort -A console -i enp0s3 -u snort -g snort -c /etc/snort/snort.conf"
sniff = sniff_command.split()

p = subprocess.Popen(sniff, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.DEVNULL, bufsize = 1)

while True:
    print(p.stdout.readline())


Tried using p.stdout.readline() as shown above but still ended up printing nothing. Answers provided to other questions, like using iter don't seem to be effective. Perhaps it's because the snort subprocess never terminates that there is an issue? At a loss, really.
A similar question was posed 8 years ago but has no answer: Snort command run through python script
Update: Thank you to Klaus D. and Boris L. for their suggestion. However, setting stderr = subprocess.STDOUT doesn't solve the problem. Although the log text (e.g. "Non-Encoded MIME attachment Extraction: Enabled") is now displayed, the actual alerts still aren't.
Also, this question was marked as a duplicate. However, the associated question's solution didn't work upon implementation.

Please explain in your question how specifically the solutions proposed in answers to the duplicate "didn't work".
